# Array to string conversion error when parsing xml data to php

Tags: php

I m new in PHP.When I try to store variable in array i got this error ** Array to string conversion **
 PHP Code is :

```
$record = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
foreach ($record as $item):       
    $a=$item->item2->record->p21;   
    $b=$item->item2->record->bq_21; 
    echo $arr1 = array($a,$b); 
endforeach;
```

I wants value only ....If print_r is used then its gives this o/p

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 26 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1 ) )
```

I want this only

```
26 1
```

Comment: It seems you need `$arr1 ` for later use, so just remove `echo` statement (although $arr1 is overwritten each time `foreach` is executed), or if you want to just print result, then `echo $a.' '.$b` like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use print_r() instead of echo

```
print_r(array($a,$b));
```

You have to cast simpleXML Object to a string. `(string)$a` and `(string)$b`

Comment: If I use this then its gives o/p in this format.Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 26 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 1 ) )..I just want value

Comment: You have to cast simpleXML Object to a string. (string)$a

Answer (score 0):

```
$record = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
foreach ($record as $item):       
    $a=$item->item2->record->p21;   
    $b=$item->item2->record->bq_21; 
    $arr1 = array($a,$b);
    print_r($arr1);
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

var_dump (http://sg3.php.net/var_dump) should be used for debugging data in an object.
Also print_r (https://www.php.net/print_r) can be used that helps printing arrays.